# Create image from running docker

Tags: docker

I created a docker based en the following image:

> https://hub.docker.com/r/tplatform/aws-linux-httpd24-php56/

I modified files an add new file in the /var/www folder in a running docker. I need to save this changes in new image but i dont know how can I do this. I checked [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#commit-a-container) but is not working for me.

Can you help me?

Comment: Show your Dockerfile

Comment: How exactly docker commit is not working for you. Because this is the way to create an image from container.

Comment: don't save the changes

Answer (score 0):

Docker commit is the tool to do what you asking. Probably you are using it wrong.
Example:

```
$ docker run -dit --name=Nginx -p 80:80 nginx
68188c608160754736f192d535742b9d0dfbc3c09564c1731741c08c211b219f
$ docker exec -it Nginx /bin/bash
root@68188c608160:/# touch New_file
root@68188c608160:/# apt-get update     
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Ign:1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                   
Get:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [454 kB]
Get:4 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
Get:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2434 B]              
Get:7 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [5152 B]
Get:8 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7099 kB]
Fetched 7864 kB in 4s (1767 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
root@68188c608160:/# exit
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
68188c608160        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   Nginx
$ docker commit Nginx nginx-updated:latest
sha256:dcc2f09f523eded0b2d33abb47e99b83453c12fb6ba958b441111f9ff40c5a8a
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx-updated                                                     latest              dcc2f09f523e        3 seconds ago       156MB
nginx                                                             latest              dbfc48660aeb        2 weeks ago         109MB
```

Comment: I do this but the changes dont save

Comment: You need to show us how you do it. Logs, command anything. Without this, I can't help you.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was running the httpd service in the docker. I do this in docker file with ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this file: `/tmp/install_and_run.sh`.
In this file you can see a line with this content: `echo "OK" > /var/www/html/index.html`.
You modify the `index.html` content and commit it to a new image. After start this image as a container this shell file will be executed (Because is in the ENTRYPOINT of Dockerfile) and overwrite your content and insert `OK` in `index.html` again!
You can do this trick to solve it:
1. Create an `index.html` in this directory for example: `/var/www/` and insert your contents to it.
2. Comment or remove this line in `/tmp/install_and_run.sh` : `echo "OK" > /var/www/html/index.html`
3. Place this code instead: `cp /var/www/index.html /var/www/html/index.html` 
Then you can commit this image to a new one and will see your modifications are saved.

Comment: I create a new clean image. My problem now is when I run the docker comitted. The problem is the service httpd is not running in the new imagen. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you realize that httpd not running? I do exactly what I mention in my post and httpd service working fine and I can see the content of new `index.html` from my browser.

Comment: In order not to complicate myself, I created a new Dockerfile. You have helped me a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: You can check the new content of `install_and_run.sh` file in this link: http://txt.do/dydpq